# Get Json Object values

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I want to get object values to print in nodejs Handlebars file. I need to print the courses and location values. Please give me the solutions on following this.

```
attributes:
{ Courses: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     Location: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
```

Answer (score 0):

To print an object's full depth of props in Node, you can use `util.inspect` like so:

```
const util = require('util');

// This is your list of courses and locations.
const values = {
    Courses: [],
    Location: []
};

console.log(util.inspect(values, { showHidden: false, depth: null }));
```

For more info, check [util.inspect](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).